# How to add SUM to nested query in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have 3 tables : `CardTypeOne` , `Card` , `TransactionMoney` .
`CardTypeOne` has a `foreign key` to `card` table (`OneToOne` relation). the `card` table has 2 foreign key to `TransactionMoney` Table (`OneToMany` relations) like below:
`CardTypeOne` Table:

```
 @OneToOne(type => Card)
    @JoinColumn()
      card: Card;
```

Card Table is:

```
@OneToMany(
    () => TransactionMoney,
    transactionMoney => transactionMoney.fromCard,
  )
  outterTransaction: TransactionMoney[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => TransactionMoney,
    transactionMoney => transactionMoney.toCard,
  )
  innerTransaction: TransactionMoney[];
```

TransactionMoney Table:

```
 @Column('integer')
  amount: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Card,
    card => card.withdraws,
  )
  outterTransaction: Card;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Card,
    card => card.deposit,
  )
  innerTransaction: Card;
```

TransactionMoney table has an amount field. I want to calculate the sum function on the outterTransaction on the amount field, and do same for innertransaction. Finally I'd like to subtract these summation.
here is my try code:

```
await getConnection()
      .getRepository(CardTypeOne)
      .createQueryBuilder('typeOne')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('typeOne.card', 'card')
      .leftJoin('card.outterTransaction','outter')
      .leftJoin('card.innerTransaction','inner')
      .addSelect('sum (outter.amount) as balance1')
      .addSelect('sum (inner.amount) as balance2')
      .where('typeOne.id= :id', { id: id})
      .getOne();
```

But when I run the code I got this error:

```
column "typeOne.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `.groupBy('typeOne.id')`?

Comment: @ArtOlshansky yes but balance1 and balance2 did not apear in the response and also I don't know how to subtract them

Comment: and also when I add the .groupBy('typeOne.id') i got the error ' column "card.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'

Comment: Let's try to add `.groupBy('typeOne.id, card.id')` _(and each of 'group by' from next errors, if the same errors will appear)_ and take a look at what you could get with it

Comment: when I add groupBy the balance1 or balance2 column is not exist in the returned data

Comment: You don't happen to have a default orderBy or other stipulation passed as an argument to your `Entity()` declarations do you? It could be auto-appending a GROUP BY or ORDER BY to a query and that's what's mucking it up. Perhaps try getting the raw sql and see if there are any unexpected clauses?

Comment: Then let's try to replace both of your `.addSelect` to `.select('sum (outter.amount) as balance1, sum (inner.amount) as balance2')`

Comment: @firxworx No i dont have a default orderBy. when I replace .getMany() with .getRawMany I can see the balance1 and balance2 in result.  but I want to use getMany()

Comment: @ArtOlshansky I change it to your code but still i cannot see it in result. also when I add these groupBy to query the result is as summation of outterTransaction and innerTransaction raws

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer were you able to solve it?